# Realm integration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I have an app that works just fine. The app is a list of cars. User can add, delete and edit cars . I tried to integrate `RealmSwift` to store data but got stuck. So far, data to operate the app is stored in static var in `Cars` class:

```
struct CarData {
    var name: String
    var year: String
}

class Cars {
    static var list = [
        CarData(name: "Toyota Corolla", year: "2007"),
        CarData(name: "BMW 3", year: "2011")
    ]
    static var index = -1
    static var newCar = false
}
```

I need realm in 2 view controllers:

1. `ListViewController` - to populate `tableView`. Something like:

```
Cars.list = realmListOfCars
```

and the rest of the code would remain the same.
2) `ConfirmViewController` - to change the stored data.

```
if toProceed {
    if Cars.newCar {
        Cars.list.append(carToEdit!) //add new car
    } else {
        Cars.list[Cars.index] = carToEdit! //edit car
    }
} else {
    if Cars.newCar == false {
        Cars.list.remove(at: Cars.index) //delete car
    }
}
//the idea is to add something like:
realmListOfCars = Cars.list
```

So the idea is to simply make `Cars.list` equal to `realmListOfCars` once loaded and make `realmListOfCars` equal to `Cars.List` once a change happens.
Sounds simple but I've got completely stuck and confused creating and accessing `realmListOfCars`.
Begging for your help!
P.S. RealmSwift is installed

Comment: Have a look at this great tutorials and then you can start with something. https://realm.io/docs/tutorials/realmtasks/, https://www.appcoda.com/realm-database-swift/

Comment: I posted an answer which should help, but I am not sure how your models are set up. You've got a Cars object which obviously contains cars but what is the `index` property for and does `newCar` mean this Cars object only contains not new cars (if it's false)? You may want to re-think that structure if so - if newCar is either true of it's list is new cars only or false if not, you would only ever have two objects; one with new cars, and one without. There may be a better way to group them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store data in Realm, you need to make your objects Realm objects. First, the Cars class would need to be changed

```
class Cars: Object {
```

and then each property you want managed would need to be updated

```
@objc dynamic var newCar = false
```

for example. You would also want to use a Realm List object as a property of the Car Data to store the cars (CarData will need to be a class, not a struct)

```
let carList = List<CarData>()
```

then, when you add a car to the Cars class carList property it will also be written to Realm as an object.

So here's your Realm objects

```
class CarData: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var year = ""
}

class Cars: Object {
    let carList = List<CarData>()
    @objc dynamic var index = -1
    @objc dynamic var newCar = false
}
```

suppose your Cars object is all McLaren's and we called it allMcLarens. Here's adding a car to that list

```
let myCar = CarData()
myCar.name = "570GT"
myCar.year = "2019"

try realm.write {
    allMcLarens.carList.append(myCar)
}
```

A lot of this is covered in the [Realm Getting Started](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) guide as well.